# How do I determine battery requirements to supply 5V USB power for an hour?

Tags: power-supply, battery, portable-harddrive

I need a USB battery that could power [Intel® Compute Stick STK2mv64CC](http://ark.intel.com/products/91979/Intel-Compute-Stick-STK2mv64CC), which requires USB 10W. How can I determine the required battery specifications to keep it powered for one hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15W at 5V is 3A.  If it needs to last an hour, that would be 3,000mAH (small batteries are typically rated in units of milliamps rather than amps).  But it's a little more complicated.

The battery voltage drops as it discharges, so you need some form of voltage adjustment to keep the output at 5V for USB purposes.  Also, the mAH rating is the total amount of energy it can hold, but not all of it will be usable for your purpose.  So you will need a battery with a higher capacity than that.  How much higher depends on the circuit used to keep the output at 5V.

So you won't be able to simply use some combination of battery cells with a nominal output of about 5V to provide USB power.  It will need to be some form of battery-based portable power pack, which will need to contain batteries with something over 3,000mAH capacity.  Assuming you purchase it rather than build it yourself, the product would, hopefully, be advertised with its run time.